# Google Analytics upgrade failure for Firebase Messaging project

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

I have an old project which I still find useful that was originally built with Google Cloud Messaging, that I then had to convert to use Firebase Cloud Messaging. I haven't worked on it for years but find it useful for my friends to track my phone's position via a web page on my always-on Raspberry Pi.

I received an e-mail from Google Analytics which said

> You are receiving this email because you own one or more Firebase
> projects using Google Analytics. With the release of Google Analytics
> 4 properties, to keep using your Firebase projects with Google
> Analytics, you must take action to accept the Google Analytics Terms
> of Service for the following projects:

I tried following the upgrade instructions via the console and get a failure due to an internal error

To the best of my knowledge I don't use any of the analytics stuff, so my question is quite simple:

**"Will my existing messaging to my phone from my web page still work?"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Sorry to hear about the problem you have when upgrading your project to GA4. Our team is aware of the problem, and working on a fix, so I recommend trying again in a few hours. Meanwhile check [this page](https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/bVj9CVqnZP1hAAtnDKjn) for status updates.

---

Firebase Cloud Messaging relies on Google Analytics data to build its dynamic audiences, which you can target when sending notification from the Firebase console. **If you don't use dynamic audiences, you don't need Google Analytics to use Firebase Cloud Messaging.**

Comment: Thank you. I see that you work for Firebase, so I'm accepting your answer. All the best, Nick